# useEffect not triggered by prop dependency

Tags: react-hooks, react-props

So I have this component set up, which has an `onClick` handler to like or unlike a certain recipe. I am using the `useEffect` hook to make sure that the icon is changed accordingly based on the `favoriteId` prop. When the `onClick` and the associated queries are executed however, the `useEffect` hook is not triggered at all, how come?

```
const RecipeCard = ({ name, image, id, favoriteId }) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthenticatedUserContext);
  const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = useState(false);


  const onLikePress = async () => {
    if (favoriteId) {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, "favorites", favoriteId));
      favoriteId = null;
    } else {
      const res = await addDoc(collection(db, "favorites"), {
        userId: user.uid,
        recipeId: id,
      });
      favoriteId = res.id;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hit");
    favoriteId ? setIsFavorite(true) : setIsFavorite(false);
  }, [favoriteId]);

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={onPress}
      style={{ flex: 1, padding: 10 }}
    >
      <View>
        <AntDesign
          onPress={() => {
            if (!user) {
              setShowNoAccountModal(true);
            } else {
              onLikePress();
            }
          }}
          name={isFavorite ? "like1" : "like2"}
          color="black"
          size={30}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};

export default RecipeCard;
```

Parent component:

```
export const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, []);

  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "receipes"));
    const fetchedRecipes = [];
    for (const d of querySnapshot.docs) {
      const citiesRef = collection(db, "favorites");
      const q = query(
        citiesRef,
        where("userId", "==", user.uid),
        where("recipeId", "==", d.id)
      );
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      const isFavorite = false;
      if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        favoriteId = null;
      } else {
        favoriteId = querySnapshot.docs[0].id;
      }
      const recipe = {
        ...d.data(),
        id: d.id,
        favoriteId,
      };
      fetchedRecipes.push(recipe);
    }
    setRecipes(fetchedRecipes);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* <Button title="Sign Out" onPress={handleLogout} /> */}
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, fontWeight: "bold", paddingBottom: 10 }}>
        Recepten
      </Text>
      {recipes && recipes.length > 0 && (
        <FlatList
          data={recipes}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <RecipeCard
              name={item.title}
              id={item.id}
              image={item.thumbnail}
              favoriteId={favoriteId}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          horizontal
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating your `favoriteId` variable, but not using `setState`, so it is not done properly and react is unaware your variable **might** have changed.
To fix this, you will need to pass a function to change your `favoriteId` prop inside of your component's parent:

```
// in parent:
const [favoriteId, setFavoriteId] = useState() // this code should be here already

return (
    // your code here
    <RecipeCard changeFavoriteId={(newId) => setFavoriteId(newId)} /> 
        // just add this changeFavoriteId prop, the old props should be here still though
    // rest of your code
)

// in RecipeCard.js
const RecipeCard = ({ name, image, id, favoriteId, changeFavoriteId }) => {
// your code here

const onLikePress = async () => {
    if (favoriteId) {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, "favorites", favoriteId));
      favoriteId = null;
    } else {
      const res = await addDoc(collection(db, "favorites"), {
        userId: user.uid,
        recipeId: id,
      });
      changeFavoriteId(res.id) // this bit here changed, now you are using setState
    }
  };

// the rest of your code
```

By using `setState` function that you obtained from parent `useState`, your component will trigger a rerender after the value is changed.

Comment: I have added the parent component code, I dont have the state set up there as you mentioned, I just pass the favoriteId (and the other props).

Comment: Then your `useEffect` won't ever fire, because your component will never render. You should set this state up if you want your `useEffect` to work

Comment: What do you mean? My component renders just fine, it is the re-render that is based on the prop that is not working.

Comment: Your rerender is not working because you are storing your variable in a plain `let favoriteId = 0` variable instead of `const [favoriteId, setFavoriteId] = useState(0)`. When you change your variable, react is **unaware** that you changed it. But when you will use `setFavoriteId`, react will notice your attempt to change the value and will rerender your component with new data.

Comment: Got it, but couldn't i then just do useState in the child component itself and populate it with the prop?

Comment: Yes, you can pass `setFavoriteId` from parent to your child component directly and then call `setFavoriteId(res.id)` directly from there, but I think it is considered a bad practice